# raise ValueError("x and y arrays must be equal in length along " ValueError: x and y arrays must be equal in length along interpolation axis

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I am working on the program to measure HRV(Heart rate Variability) analysis, but I am getting an error as below.

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

meaures = [peaklist]

print('this peaklist is for measuring of frequency domain maesures', peaklist)

RR_x = peaklist[1:]

print('RR_X IS : ', RR_x)

RR_y = RR_interval_list

print('RR_Y IS : ', RR_y)

RR_x_new = np.linspace(RR_x[0], RR_x[-1],RR_x[-1])

print("RR_X_NEW IS : ", RR_x_new)

f = interp1d(RR_x_new, RR_y, kind='cubic')

print('f is : ',f(250))
```

this peaklist is for measuring of frequency domain maesures

```
[63, 165, 264, 360, 460, 565, 674, 773, 863, 953, 1048, 1156, 1272, 1385, 1487, 1592, 1698, 1803, 1897, 1994, 2097, 2206, 2308, 2406]
```

RR_X IS :

```
[165, 264, 360, 460, 565, 674, 773, 863, 953, 1048, 1156, 1272, 1385, 1487, 1592, 1698, 1803, 1897, 1994, 2097, 2206, 2308, 2406]
```

RR_Y IS :

```
[1020.0, 990.0, 960.0, 1000.0, 1050.0, 1090.0, 990.0, 900.0, 900.0, 950.0, 1080.0, 1160.0, 1130.0, 1020.0, 1050.0, 1060.0, 1050.0, 940.0, 970.0, 1030.0, 1090.0, 1020.0, 980.0]
```

RR_X_NEW IS :

```
[ 165.          165.93180873  166.86361746 ... 2404.13638254 2405.06819127
 2406.        ]
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Dee1/PycharmProjects/HeartAna1.1/HeartAna.py", line 235, in
>   
>       f = interp1d(RR_x_new, RR_y, kind='cubic')   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\HeartAna1.1\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py",
>   line 433, in **init**
>       _Interpolator1D.**init**(self, x, y, axis=axis)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\HeartAna1.1\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\polyint.py",
>   line 60, in **init**
>       self._set_yi(yi, xi=xi, axis=axis)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\HeartAna1.1\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\polyint.py",
>   line 125, in _set_yi
>       raise ValueError("x and y arrays must be equal in length along " ValueError: x and y arrays must be equal in length along interpolation
>   axis.

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

That's not how `interp1d` is designed to work. The `x` and `y` arguments must have the same length. Using your example, what you want to do is:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

RR_x = [165, 264, 360, 460, 565, 674, 773, 863, 953, 1048, 1156, 1272, 1385, 1487, 1592, 1698, 1803, 1897, 1994, 2097, 2206, 2308, 2406]
RR_y = [1020.0, 990.0, 960.0, 1000.0, 1050.0, 1090.0, 990.0, 900.0, 900.0, 950.0, 1080.0, 1160.0, 1130.0, 1020.0, 1050.0, 1060.0, 1050.0, 940.0, 970.0, 1030.0, 1090.0, 1020.0, 980.0]

f = interp1d(RR_x, RR_y, kind='cubic')
RR_x_new = np.linspace(RR_x[0], RR_x[-1], RR_x[-1])
RR_y_new = f(RR_x_new)

print(RR_y_new)
# array([1020. , 1020.07989053, 1020.14949355, ...,  979.18255462, 979.58047408, 980. ])
```